# Show repeated background with various size images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to show the repeated background in the layout. When I use the bitmap resource it can use only one image. So, I have the same size photo(48x48 in my case)in all screen. But I want to show image depends on screen size as we do in launcher icon. I have five images in mipmap folder and how can I use these images?
Following is my code,

res/drawable/repeated_background.xml

```
<resources>
<bitmap 
    xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:src="@drawable/background_img.png"
    android:tileMode="repeated"/>
</resources>
```

res/layout/activity.xml

```
<RelaytiveLayout
  ............
  android:background="@drawable/repeated_background"
  ..........>
```

Comment: Those images are selected automatically by the framework according to the device your app is installed on.

Comment: @jvrodrigues Couldn't I use various size image for repeated background?

Comment: The mipmap folder/s should contain **only the app icon**. And **nothing else**, as stated on the android developer site.

Comment: @ModularSynth How can I use various images such as (48x48)(96x96)(144x144) for repeated background?

Comment: Properly put them in the drawable/s folders

Comment: @ModularSynth Do I need to make folder such as drawable-hdpi, drawale-xhdpi, etc.?

Comment: Yes, as usual. If not already existing, create the folders you need.

Comment: @ModularSynth I tested it and it worked properly. Thanks for your comment. Why don't android studio create drawable-xxx folder for us?

Comment: Because it doesn't know which ones we will use and which ones we won't? Anyway, not a big deal, is it?